# Any way to generate Intellij run configurations?

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration-files, intellij-plugin, run-configuration

it would be great to generate run configurations in Intellij IDEA using a script. I did not find any API for that. I found `runConfigurations.xml` and `workspace.xml` in the `.idea` directory, but did not find any documentation about it's structure. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you clarify your use case? You can try creating a custom plugin based on IntelliJ platform. See the related tutorial https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/run-configurations.html .

Comment: @Egor Klepikov Thanks, I'll try that. I'm installing and running lots of services after cloning or merging them fron git. This is a relatively boring and repetitive task, so I thought I should automate it.